# Как сложить две строки?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> // для _getch()
#include <clocale> // для погдключения русской локали 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>  //strcat

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian_Russia.1251");
    char* slovo1  =  " proger ";
    char* slovo2  =  " riger ";

    //strcpy (slovo1,slovo2);
    strcat (slovo1, slovo2);
    printf(slovo1);
    //printf("прива");
    cout << "\n" << slovo1<< "\n";
    printf("прива");

    std::cout << " Press <Enter> ... ";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Необработанное исключение в "0x003fd2e9 (msvcr100d.dll)" в "test1.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при записи "0x00a47868".

Comment: **не получается**

Comment: А память кто выделять будет? Срочно курить строки и распределение памяти.

Comment: Почему тег стоит **c++**?! В С++ объявляем строки через стандартный класс `std::string`. У него реализован оператор `+`, так и прибавляем. Для чистого C читайте `man asprintf`.

Comment: Так С или С++? В С++ ни о каком `char* slovo2  =  " riger ";` речи быть не может, но вдруг используется `std::cout`. Что это за каша?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в строчке

```
strcat (slovo1, slovo2);
```

Функция `strcat` присоединяет к строке, переданной первым параметром, строку, переданную вторым параметром. В данном случае строки - это массивы элементов типа `char`. В C++ массивы не являются динамическими структурами, то есть не могут изменять свой размер во время выполнения программы. Поэтому в массиве (строке), переданном первым параметром в `strcat`, должно быть достаточно места, чтобы туда поместились обе строки. Объявляя строку так

```
char* slovo1  =  " proger ";
```

вы создаёте массив `char`'ов размером ровно в длину строки `" proger "` (плюс один элемент под нуль-терминатор). Если вы хотите сложить две строки, вам придётся выделить память под результат:

```
cahr* slovo = new char[strlen(slovo1) + strlen(slovo2) + 1];
strcat(slovo, slovo1);
strcat(slovo, slovo2);
printf(slovo);
```

Есть и другие способы. Например, с использованием класса [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/):

```
stringstream ss;
ss << slovo1 << slovo2;
printf(ss.str().c_str());  // ну, или cout << ss;
```

Или используя класс [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/):

```
string slovo1 = " proger ";
string slovo2 = " riger ";
slovo1 = slovo1 + slovo2;
cout << slovo1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы либо пишите на С++, либо на С. У вас же какая-то каша. Если это С, то для указателей char* выделяйте память, используйте правильно printf, или же puts вместо неё для вывода. Если С++, то конкатенация строки сделайте как string и конкатенация +.
Обращайте внимание на то, что говорит компилятор в процессе компиляции, g++ на вашу программу выдал следующее, это как раз о том, что я выше написал:

```
main.cpp:10:22: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     char* slovo1  =  " proger ";
                      ^
main.cpp:11:22: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     char* slovo2  =  " riger ";
                      ^
main.cpp:15:18: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
     printf(slovo1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Это все, конечно, верно, но реальная причина ошибки заключается в попытке **записи в область констант**.

Обычно (как в этом случае) эта область памяти имеет защиту от модификации.

--

[[@timob256](/users/23344/timob256)](/users/23344/timob256), достаточно написать (не скажу, что *так надо программировать*)

```
 char proger[100 /* достаточно большое число */] = " proger ",
   *slovo1 = proger, *slovo2 = " riger ";
```

и *данная ошибка* исчезнет.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const char* a = "blabla";                           // статический
    char* b = new char[10];                             // динамический
    memcpy(b, "BLABLABLA", 10);
    auto la = strlen(a);
    auto lb = strlen(b);
    char* c = new char[la + lb + 1];                    // динамический
    memcpy(c, a, la);
    memcpy(c + la, b, lb + 1);
    cout << c << endl;
    delete[] c;
    delete[] b;
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. string ? не, не слышал...

Answer (score 0):

Для полноты картины стоит выложить ответ на СИ.

Вот код :3 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //--
    char* slovo1  =  " proger ";
    char* slovo2  =  " riger ";
    char *result1 = malloc(strlen(slovo1)+strlen(slovo2)+1);//+1 для нуль терминатора
    //также для " реального кода " сюда стоит поставить проверку на ошибки malloc-а 
    strcpy(result1, slovo1 ); // функция нуль терминированной строки (первым дело через strcpy вставляем, а последующие через strcat)
    strcat(result1, slovo2); // функция копирования в строку
    printf(result1);
    //--
    return 0;
}
```